# Entity Framework - Skipping objects in navigation path

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have three entities based on 3 DB tables, (cardinality below the relationships).

```
Pupil - SchoolClass - ClassType
     N:1           1:1
```

I want to fetch a list of pupils and update their scalar property `Grade`.
The Grade depends on the class type the pupil attends. So I also need the ClassType for each Pupil.

This is what I do:

```
var pupils = from pupil in db.Pupils.Include("SchoolClass.ClassType")
             select pupil;

foreach(Pupil p in pupils)
    p.Grade *= p.SchoolClass.ClassType.GradingFactor;
```

The problem with this is that the SchoolClass is loaded into the context, with all the scalar properties filled in (+ foreign key IDs).

Is there a way to skip an object in between the Pupil and the ClassType entities? That is, to load only SchoolClass' ClassType navigation property?

Loading desired number of pupils without Include was 20 ms, and with Include it was 250 ms. I am wondering if this can be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

Loading the desired number of puples without an include was just a select on 1 table without segmentation or sorting if i get your query right. That ofcourse is faster.

Now you load in all navigation properties. Thats some work. Have you thought of only selecting the Pupil and its GradingFactor?

```
var pupils = from pupil in db.Pupils 
             select new
             {
                Pupil = pupil,
                GradingFactor = pupil.SchoolClass.ClassType.GradingFactor
             };
```

Another optimalisation would be to merge SchoolClass and ClassType together since their relationship is 1:1 (according to your specification) saving you 1 join

Comment: did you mean pupil.SchoolClass.ClassType.GradingFactor?